# Gmail filter based on X-OriginatorOrg header?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I'm looking to create a filter in Gmail that will take any email with a certain `X-OriginatorOrg` header value (e.g., `example.com`) and move it to a certain label. I've looked at the [advanced search operators](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190) list on Google's help pages, but I can't seem to find anything that will enable me to search any value in the message headers, even if Gmail hasn't specifically created a search operator for it.

Is this at all possible with Gmail? If not, is there a third-party Gmail app in existence that offers this functionality?